how to secure custom activity endpoint other than of /save,/publish,/validate and /execute
Inside my journey builder custom activity i am using custom endpoint to retrieve information and display in UI, i am thinking hosting custom activity as an static website (/public). we can specify useJwt: true option for endpoint specified inside config.json or specify:
"securityOptions": {
        "securityType": "securityContext",
        "securityContextKey": "<externalKeyName>"
      }

but how to use similar kind of convention to secure outgoing request from custom activity to custom rest endpoint, i can implement own authentication mechanism inside my api but doing so i need to specify api credentials publicly inside static js assets.

Not sure you can really host the REST endpoints on a static site as they need to be able to verify JWT tokens. For your UI route, can you not just piggyback off SFMC's authentication token to authenticate the user or do you need other information to authenticate against some other service?
